# Probability - Re-adding the same values into the selection

Tags: probability

**Scenario 1**

Let's say we have 12 people and 6 teams to choose from (Team-A through to Team-F).

Firstly, all 6 teams go into a hat and then the first 6 people randomly select one team each. Once the 6th person has picked the last team, the 6 teams are then put back into the hat and then the remaining six people repeat the process of each picking one team.

**Scenario 2**

Let's say we have 12 people and 6 teams to choose from (Team-A through to Team-F). But this time we will put 2 of each team into the hat so there are 12 teams in total.

This time each of the 12 people take it in turns to randomly select 1 team out of the hat until all teams are gone and everyone has one team each.

**Question**

One team will be the winning team.

Is the odds/probability identical in both scenarios of picking the winning team for all participants?

Comment: Probability of what?

Comment: Sorry my bad, the probability of picking the correct winning team

Comment: It is still $\frac{1}{6}$ for individual winners in each type of sweepstake, but there are different probabilities of pairs of winners in the two scenarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, it's the same.**

This can be shown fairly easily through an argument of symmetry. If the probability of a particular person picking the winning team would be less than $1/6$ for either case, the probability of picking some other team would have to be conversely higher since the sum off all possible events must be $1$. However, since all teams receive identical treatment, there can't be a team with higher probability of being picked by a particular person.

**What does change between the two cases?**

In the first case, there's only one of each team for the first six people, and another one for the last six. This means the winning team will always be picked by one person from the first six and one from the last six, never two from the first six or two from the last six. In the latter case it's possible for both winners to be in the first six, or for both winners to be in the latter six. This does not affect any particular person's chance of winning.